# Inside a 'change' EventListener, can I determine what triggered it? (What was clicked?)

Tags: javascript

I added an EventListener to all the input elements in my form. Inside the event handler, I validate the input and display an error message if invalid.

HTML:

```
<div id="forminputs">
<div class="password-container">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-eye" onClick="showHide();" id="eye"></i>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const delegate = (selector) => (cb) => (e) => e.target.matches(selector) && cb(e);
const inputDelegate = delegate('input');
forminputs.addEventListener('change', inputDelegate((el) => {
    checkEntry(el.target);
    }
   ));
```

Everything was working fine. But now I position the eye icon (show/hide) inside the password input box. When the icon is clicked, the typed characters are displayed/hidden.

CSS:

```
.password-container{
  width: 550px;
  position: relative;
}.password-container input[type="password"],
.password-container input[type="text"]{
  width: 100%;
  /* padding: 12px 36px 12px 12px; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}.fa-eye{
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  right: 4%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lightgray;
}
```

JS:

```
showHide(){
this.classList.toggle("fa-eye-slash");
const type = passwordField.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
 passwordField.setAttribute("type", type);
}
```

The problem is that the 'change' event is called first before the onClick event for the icon. But I don't want to verify the password yet, if it's just the icon that was clicked.

Is there a way to check inside the change event handler what was clicked? Or can this be done some other way?

[EDIT NOTE: This code is part of a much larger system. I hope I able to include all the relevant pieces. ]

Comment: What is `inputDelegate` and what does it have to do with your question?

Comment: Sorry, it was missing. I just added it.

Comment: Your addition doesn't tell us very much, nowhere in your example code do you show what `forminputs` is, or what `delegate` is.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What does `delegate` do? Is it from a library? Is it targeting _all_ inputs or just one?

Comment: It sounds like you need to keep the events coming from the icon from bubbling up, but its hard to say without more information. Clicking the icon should not cause a `change` event for the input.

Comment: _"But now I added a "show/hide" icon inside the password input box."_ I doubt that. The OP most probably positioned another element (the icon containing one)  on top (or in front of) the input element. Please OP provide a boiled down variant of your code as executable [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid that the input element triggers a `change` event when the user clicks on the icon, listen to the `mousedown` event on the icon, and call `preventDefault` on the event object. Something like this:

```
icon.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Perform the show/hide logic here    
});
```